# output of commands "report", "set", or "let"

Tags: netlogo

How can I see the output of commands "report" in a reporter procedure (to-report), "set", or "let" ?

For example, I don't know how I can see the output of 
"poly-turtle" in

```
set poly-turtles (turtle-set poly-turtles self)
```

and the output of "poly-turtle" in

```
report poly-turtles
```

I would like to know the difference between "report" and "set" commands.
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "see the output". If you just want to see it on the screen, you can use [`output-print`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#output-print) or related commands. For example:

```
output-print poly-turtles
```

...will print the value of the `poly-turtles` variable in your model's output area (or the command center if there is no output area).

As for the difference between [`set`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#set) and [`report`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#report), well, they are not at all like each other. You should read about [variables](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#variables) and [procedures](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#procedures) in the user manual, but in a nutshell:

- [`set`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#set) changes the value of a variable. It is what you would do with the `=` operator in most imperative languages.
- [`report`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#report) exits the current reporter and tell it which value to return to the caller. It is, as you might have guessed, the equivalent of `return` in many languages.